# Is having hashes of document certificates in EOS blockchain for tamper proof a good use case for EOS?

Tags: eosjs, eosio-code

I have a application where I want to store a SHA256 hash of a document in a Blockchain. I want it to have a good life, ie storing the SHA256 hasha as a data in a transaction should bot be deleted quickly. It should last for several years. Also, I want to have transaction where cost are very low unlike ethereum.

My question is:

- Is this having a SHA256 hashes store in a EOS blockchain a good use case for EOS?
- Also, what is the transaction fees for each transaction where I store a hash of the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it depends on the use case.  IPFS is a distributed file storage system that is hash addressed, so if you just want to make sure you're accessing the right file, then you could just use the IPFS address to access it always.  If you also want to show when the document was created or manage CRUD processes, blockchain may be your database of choice.

Storing a sha256 in general for preservation is good and in general I think this will be what the eos mainnet is used for (posting hashes as integrity checkpoints of other chains).

Trx fee would be the cost of CPU to rent from the resource exchange (REX).

Resource Price:
1 EOS Can Borrow 3,922.9761 EOS for 30 days (I've seen this as low as 300 EOS and probably much higher, the market fluctuates based on liquidity and demand)
https://bloks.io/rex

So basically pennies to post thousands of hashes I'd say for a relative idea, wayyyy cheaper than any POW chain.

Comment: Okay. So EOS looks good fit for storing hashes to timestamp them. Do you have their discord or some channel to be part of their group?

Comment: Yup we do things on the gram https://t.me/joinchat/DQRZHEPktgcLlyfbl-bDuQ